# Passing substring in C

Tags: c, string, substring

I've spent last night debugging this little piece of code. I have two data text files, both contain 18000 chars. Id like to split these 18000 into two sub-strings each of 100 chars, that makes 180 iterations.

The tricky thing is, in the first 180 iterations the size of both sub-strings is fine. After 18 iterations, the sizes of the sub-strings are 0.

Both files were opened properly. I can print them and so on. I tried to allocate the sub-strings in all the possible ways I could think of but could find no solution so far.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) { 

    //Ive loaded two files into two strings buff1 and buff2 both size of 18000 chars
    //It works fine with small data example, I dunno why but eventually I have work with much more bigger data set
    //Id like to divide them into 100 char long pieces and do some stuff with that 

    char *substrA;      //substring for buff1
    char *substrB;      //substring for buff2

    substrA = malloc((wlen+1)*sizeof(char));        //word length wlen=100
    substrA = malloc((wlen+1)*sizeof(char));

    for (int i= 0; i <numOfSubProblems; ++i){   //numOfSubProblems = 18000/100

        strncpy(substrA, buff1+i*wlen, wlen);
        strncpy(substrB, buff2+i*wlen, wlen);
        substrA[wlen] = '\0';
        substrA[wlen] = '\0';

        int lenA = strlen(substrA);
        int lenB = strlen(substrB);
        printf("STRA a STR B: %d %d \n",lenA,lenB);

        DoSomething(substrA,substrB,i);  //some parser and other functionality
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are `subA` and `subB` declared?

Comment: What about using `strndup()` instead of `malloc()`+`strncpy()`?

Comment: So: what's the problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 7):

`strncpy` does not null-terminate the destination string. So you have to do

```
strncpy(subA, buff1+i*wlen, wlen);
subA[wlen] = '\0';
strncpy(subB, buff2+i*wlen, wlen);
subB[wlen] = '\0';
```

Otherwise you cannot use `strlen`, and you access the buffers behind their end when doing so.

Comment: Oh my god Im such an idiot, thanks that solved size problem, but still there is issue with with those iterations, after 18th same problem

Comment: `strncpy` very well terminates the destination string **unless** it does not fit into the destination array. As the destrination array is guaranted to be long enough, one can as well use `strcpy` or pass `wlen + 1`. But here `memcpy` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It does not terminate the string, it copies the '\0' if it is part of the first `len` characters (ok, basically the same result)

Comment: @JerrySmith  I know buff1 and buff2 have 18000 characters, but what are the length of the strings in buff1 and buff2?

Comment: @KarstenKoop and since the source is a string with length > `wlen`, it does not copy a NUL character. QED.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis +1 for the Latin ;)

Comment: Thank you Michael, I just found out that for some reason those files are not loaded properly, it only loads 1800 char to the buff1 and buff2 not 18000 as it supposed

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf`.

You may not be dealing with formatting strings, but at least it is a sane API. Also make sure to round up when determining the number of subproblems:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PROBSIZE 18002

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char input[PROBSIZE];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < PROBSIZE; ++i) {
        input[i] = 'A' + (i % 10);
    }

    const size_t wlen = 10;
    char *subA = malloc (wlen + 1);
    if (!subA) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (PROBSIZE + wlen - 1) / wlen; ++i) {
        /* If there's no error, guarantees `wlen` characters copied */
        int err = snprintf(subA, wlen + 1, "%s", input + i * wlen);

        if (err < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "snprintf encountered an error\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* In absence of errors, we expect that the return value is
         * always >= wlen + 1, except the last iteration.
         */
        assert(err >= wlen + 1 || i == ((PROBSIZE + wlen - 1) / wlen) - 1);

        printf("%s\n", subA);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```